# Dependency injection and object creation

Tags: dependency-injection

When I use dependency injection, I create **all** objects at the very beginning of the program.

I end up having to carry dependencies through a lot of constructors, although it would be more easy to create them somewhere earlier.

The pattern of factories comes to mind. Factory can be passed in the constructor to not violate DI.

But isn't this an anti-pattern / violating of DI? Since Factory creates a concrete implementation of the object?

What are the approaches to create objects without breaking DI?

Answer (score 1):

When practicing DI, there is no need or requirement to construct all objects at startup; that's a design choice or perhaps a design constraint in your particular environment. In fact, lazy initialization with DI is the norm—not the exception.

But the consequence of lazy initialization of object graphs is that you typically have some factory-like behavior *somewhere* in the application.

Many application types, like web application frameworks, provide a factory abstraction that you can implement or override that allows you to create the necessary objects for the request that comes in.

If you do this, and create the object structure specific for a request, just in time when a request comes in, I'd say that in most cases there is no need for postponing the creation of other objects for that request. This means there's no need for injecting any factory classes into the classes of your application. I'd say that in most cases, [Abstract Factories are a Design Smell](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/abstract-factories/).

But there are exceptions, though, and the argument that Abstract Factories should be reviewed with suspicion, doesn't mean that you don't need *factory-like behavior* somewhere inside your code. Whenever you're doing message dispatching, for instance, where an incoming message gets dispatched to one or multiple handlers, where many handler classes exist in the application, requires lazy initialization of classes, and requires factory-like behavior. This, however, can be hidden behind abstractions that are implemented inside the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/), which prevents application code from depending on an Abstract Factory.

But that said, not all application frameworks expose factory abstractions for you to implement, and as I said, there are always exceptions to the rule.